# Inserting multiple rows in a single SQL query from C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have multiple set of data to insert at once, say 10 rows.

My table has three columns: `PlanId`,`MomEntryId` and `CreatedBy`

Can I insert all 10 rows in a single SQL statement?

This is my Store procedure. How can I pass 10 rows values in SP. I need to validate that `PlanId` and `MomEntryId` too that it's value is `greater than zero` or not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Document_Plan_Or_MomEntry_Insert
@PlanId int = null,
@MomEntryId int = null,
@CreatedBy varchar(20)  
AS
BEGIN
    if(@PlanId > 0)
    begin
        Insert into t_Document(PlanId,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
        values
        (@PlanId,@CreatedBy,GETDATE())
    end
    else if (@MomEntryId>0)
    begin
        Insert into t_Document([MomEntryId],CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
        values
        (@MomEntryId,@CreatedBy,GETDATE())
    end
END
GO
```

Below is my C# code for passing parameters.

```
  cblCheckList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToList().ForEach(d =>
                    {
                        if(d.Selected)
                        {
                            momEntry.AddDocumentDetailForMomEntry(Convert.ToInt32(d.Value), Session["userId"].ToString());
                        }
                    });
```

and this is for Datalayer code.I use `Enterprise library` file for creating DbHelper class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MOMGateway
/// </summary>
public class MOMGateway
{
    private MOMGateway()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

   ///
   /// This method perform insert operation in Document table
   ///
    public static int AddDocumentEntryforMomEntry(int momEntryId,string createdBy)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(DBHelper.GetDatabase().ExecuteScalar("SP_Document_Plan_Or_MomEntry_Insert",
                      null,momEntryId,createdBy));
        return i;
    }



}
```

Comment: Have you considered SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: @Sruti: Yes but same time need to perform validation too.

Comment: Can you not perform the validation on the C# side, ease of unit testing comes for free :)

Answer (score 1):

> This is my Store procedure. How can I pass 10 rows values in SP

Use [User Defined Table Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for this purpose. You can pass the `DataTable` or your collection of object from C# code as parameter to your defined table type.

See: [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server 2008 and C#](http://orionseven.com/blog/2009/09/30/using-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-c/)

Comment: How I will validate the PlanId and MomEntryId in my SP

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi, see [this article](http://blogical.se/blogs/mikael/archive/2011/12/15/using-user-defined-tables-as-stored-procedure-parameter.aspx),

Comment: I need to validate that If PlanId > 0 then only PlanId value insert perform other wise MomEntryId. Both entry not perform on same page

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi if you follow the link , there is store proc in it. you may validate things there.

Comment: @Habib , Can we have this adapter other than WCF .

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi, also the UDT will be like a table, you can perform join with the existing table to see if the ID exist and insert/update accordingly

Comment: @faheemkhan, oh yeah sure, it can be.